# Linking error gsoap in mac in c

Tags: c, macos, gsoap

I try to add gsoap in my application.
I built gsoap for i386.
Created c code with under commands:

```
wsdl2h -c -s -o soap.h soap.wsdl 
soapcpp2 -c -C soap.h
```

I got files. After this I tried to include these to my app.
I added to my project in xCode. Also I added 6 libraries(libgsoap.a,libgsoap++.a,libgsoapck.a, libgsoapck++.a, libgsoapssl.a, libgsoapssl++.a). I added libraries in Target => Build phases => Link binary with libraries.
But I got error....

```
ld: duplicate symbol .....
```

I thought it happened cause in file soapClientLib.c was it:

```
#ifndef WITH_NOGLOBAL
#define WITH_NOGLOBAL
#endif
#define SOAP_FMAC3 static
#include "soapC.c"
#include "soapClient.c"
```

Comments for these was:

```
Use this file in your project build instead of the two files soapC.c and soapClient.c. This hides the serializer functions and avoids linking problems when linking multiple clients and servers
```

I removed it content.
But after this I got next error...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_namespaces", referenced from:
      _soap_init_LIBRARY_VERSION_REQUIRED_20812 in libgsoap.a(libgsoap_a-stdsoap2.o)
     (maybe you meant: _soap_set_namespaces, _soap_set_local_namespaces )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And Now I have no idea...
I used gsoap in windows and I added it to my project for 5 minutes. But I wasted much time to add it in mac os.
Can you help me?

Comment: I didn't write it. It was generated by gsoap. I removed it. But now I have another error

Comment: If that is what was generated then you shouldn't have removed it.  Are you sure you should link with **all** those libraries?  I use gsoap at work (so I know how crap it is) and I'm sure we don't link with all of those libraries...

Comment: I have similar issue with gsoap. I'm tring to compile using gcc but got linker error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:"  Command I used: gcc -o tdc_send_sms tdc_send_sms.c -L/usr/local/lib/ -lgsoap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem!
I had to do ./configure with keys --disable-namespaces.
Thank you.
But I steal don't understand sense of the file soapClientLib.c.

Comment: Accept your own answer then.

Answer (score 1):

I know, that this is an old question, but I've just spent an entire evening figuring this out.

Here is a quote from [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.text.xml.soap.gsoap/2871) conversation ([another link](http://markmail.org/message/c4lzp3lgwnxjq4jz)):

> The soapcpp2-generated `xyz.nsmap` file should be `#include`'d in your code. It
>   contains a global XML namespace mapping (or binding) table.
>
> The reason for including this separately is that there are scenarios where the
>   namespace mapping table is customized or shared.

For instance, I used a C++ classes, generated with `soapcpp2 -i <my_header.h>`. One of generated files is a `<my_service_name>Service.cpp`. To get rid of the `_namespaces` issue I had to `#include "<my_service_name>.nsmap"` in it.

As for the `soapClientLib.c`, I's like to quote that conversation again:

> Please do not use soapClientLib.c in your build unless you want to combine
>   multiple separately-generated clients/server codes. This means that the
>   soapClientLib.c do not include the shared serializers for SOAP headers and
>   faults.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer; don't forget to `#include "whatever.nsmap"` in your source!

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved with changing compiler filename from gcc to g++.

GCC:

```
gcc calcmain.cpp soapC.cpp soapcalcProxy.cpp  -I/opt/local/include -lgsoap++ -L/opt/local/lib
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

G++:

```
g++ calcmain.cpp soapC.cpp soapcalcProxy.cpp  -I/opt/local/include -lgsoap++ -L/opt/local/lib
All OK
```

Yet you can make it compilable under gcc, with adding an gcc option -lstdc++:

```
gcc calcmain.cpp soapC.cpp soapcalcProxy.cpp  -I/opt/local/include -lgsoap++ -L/opt/local/lib -lstdc++
All OK
```